# How to add error from rest api to binding result

Tags: spring, error-handling, request, resttemplate

I have REST API and app with few controllers.
I have post request in app which send form to create new Driver to rest api and try to save it in database:

```
@PostMapping("/create")
public String post(ModelMap modelMap, @ModelAttribute CreateDriverForm createDriverForm,
                   BindingResult bindingResult) throws JsonProcessingException {
    DriverDTO driverDTO = driverService.create(createDriverForm);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors().stream()
                .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
        modelMapHelper.addBasicAttributesToDriversSite(modelMap);
        return "/drivers/drivers";
    }
    modelMap.addAttribute("driver", driverDTO);
    modelMap.addAttribute("message", "Created driver: ");
    return "/drivers/drivers_profile";
}
```

My method in service looks like:

```
public DriverDTO create(CreateDriverForm createDriverForm) throws JsonProcessingException {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    DriverRequestModel driverRequestModel = new DriverRequestModel(
            createDriverForm.getName(), createDriverForm.getSurname(), createDriverForm.getEmail());

    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(driverRequestModel, httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
            restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8081/drivers", entity, String.class);

    return objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), DriverDTO.class);
}
```

If form has any errors rest api returns custom object from global exception handler for example:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-03T13:18:05.3352166",
    "status": 400,
    "errorName": "MethodArgumentNotValidException",
    "message": "[Email already exists]"
}
```

And now I would like to catch message from error and put it into binding results and use it on my html template. How should I do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Either you use @Controller or use @Restcontroller with below example code .

```
  @PostMapping("/create")
    public DriverDTO post(@RequestBody CreateDriverForm createDriverForm,
                       BindingResult bindingResult) throws JsonProcessingException {
        DriverDTO driverDTO = driverService.create(createDriverForm);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           //throw exception
}
       return driverDTO;
    }
```